# Modify the ports for the exposed API in WSO2 API manager

Tags: wso2

I have to expose an API with the port other than 8280. i modified that in axis2.xml  to port :8286 for HTTP Transportreceiver . Even after restarting the  apigateway service , it is Refusing the connection on the particualar port.
     Whats the process for modifying the ports.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the Port offset of the API Manager Server. For that change  offset configuration in `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml`

```
<Offset>1</Offset>
```

This will change the NIO port which is 8280 by default to 8281 (8280 + 1).

After that make sure to edit all the hardcoded endpoints of default APIs available by following[1]

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Configuring+Port+Offset